# How can I create a natural fading effect on planets in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I've have experience with CAD but am a complete Blender (especially the Cycles engine) noob. Recently I've been doing a lot of self-learning, then I came across this image:

[image: landscape image]

Could anyone please tell me how to achieve a natural fading effect on the planets? My nodes are a mess but the result still comes off as too "stiff" and "mechanical".

Hope that I've explained myself well enough and that you guys understand!

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64517/how-can-i-blend-a-moon-planet-textured-sphere-into-the-background-procedural/64520#64520

Comment: are you looking for the fog in the distance, or the fading the the colors on the hills?

Comment: You definitely need a sand wind texture thing like in the picture you posted

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting/answering! sambler & cegaton: will be experimenting more with the methods provided. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fade the moons, I would use a spherical gradient texture to mix between the moon texture and transparency.

[image: sample moon]

Use a mapping node to position and scale the gradient into position.

A colour ramp and math node can be used to control how quick you transition from texture to transparent.

[image: example nodes]

Answer (score 9):

Use Volume absorption and volume scattering as volume on a mesh that completely surrounds your scene.

[image]

[image]

Play around with a  texture for the density and you'll be able to make clouds and all kinds of fun stuff.

Comment: Wow! I seldom partake in online communities, but I've heard about how helpful and friendly the Blender community is. Now that I'm receiving an overwhelming level of assistance, I've got to say, you guys are wonderful! :D Thank you!