# how do I make a realistic moon on a day sky in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I had a node setup as shown in the picture. although I still have to plug in the bump and diffuse maps, I wanted to see the effect that the darker side of the moon is not black but the color of the sky. what changes should I make in my node setup? [image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64517/how-can-i-blend-a-moon-planet-textured-sphere-into-the-background-procedural/64520#64520

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67666/how-can-i-create-a-natural-fading-effect-on-planets-in-cycles/67699#67699