# How would I make something look super far off and really big while having that white kind of haze to it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, objects

I want to put a ship over a city but make it look really big and have that white hazy look to it, like the death star has here. See how it's transparent-ish and kind of smokey white? How do I do this in blender(cycles)?[image]

[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64517/how-can-i-blend-a-moon-planet-textured-sphere-into-the-background-procedural/64520#64520 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67666/how-can-i-create-a-natural-fading-effect-on-planets-in-cycles

Comment: Yeah I solved the problem, thanks Duarte Farrajota Ramos