# Moon effect - during the day, blue sky, half of the moon, part of the moon, moon phase,

Tags: texturing, node-editor

[image]

I managed to achieve this type of effect, but I am looking closer to the moon during the day, that is not visible partially. How do I achieve the same effect?
[image]
[image]

I was trying to use this set up but it doesn't work for me
[How can I blend a moon/planet (textured sphere) into the background (procedural sky texture)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64517/how-can-i-blend-a-moon-planet-textured-sphere-into-the-background-procedural)
[image]

Comment: Hello, please be more descriptive about your problem. Right now it's a guessing game for anyone trying to help you

Comment: @Gorgious I am trying to make a moon that is blending with the sky. I only know how to make a full moon, but what about other types of moon? How do I do it?

Comment: I would try the physically correct way, either place your sun light on the right or left of your moon, or place your camera on the left or right of your moon

Comment: What from the linked question does not work for you?